# Why I can't assign a char pointer to a string after initializing it to NULL at Global area

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, null

when I try to initialize a char pointer to NULL and then try to assign it to a string it gives me build error as following :

```
error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit int [-Wimplicit-int]
Ptr = "NULL";
^
int
error: redefinition of 'Ptr' with a different type: 'int' vs 'char *'
note: previous definition is herechar *Ptr = NULL;
```

I've tried to understand it but I couldn't.

So I've tried this following code but it always gives me build error when I give the pointer an initial value to NULL and then try to change it.

```
char *Ptr = NULL;
Ptr = "NULL";
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

if I directly initialized the pointer to a string it would work ...
also it would work in following [as local]

```
int main()
{
    char *Ptr = NULL;
    Ptr = "NULL";
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone just clarify how things are going on there..

Comment: `Ptr = "NULL";` is a non-declaration statement. You can't have those outside of functions. To be frank, your teacher or books or other learning material should have taught you that.

Comment: You can’t have that statement outside of a function. It’s a new declaration

Comment: @M_G_0xFF, Code in `main()` is nominally sequential.  `Ptr = NULL;` initialization happens first then, `Ptr = "NULL";`.  Global variables are conceptually initialized all at once.  Sequential code like `Ptr = "NULL";` is not allowed there.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it’s a declaration based on the warning

Comment: @DanielA.White Looks like the compiler is treating it as an implicit `int` declaration. That may be a compiler extension.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute code outside functions in C. The language was not designed to support that. You may however initialize variables defined outside functions, as long as you initialize them to a compile-time constant.

- `char *Ptr = NULL;` is such an initialization, it is valid C.
- `Ptr = "NULL";` is not an initialization since there is no variable type specified. Instead, this looks like a run-time assignment, which cannot be placed outside a function body.

Your compiler actually thinks that `Ptr = "NULL";` is a separate variable definition and initialization. So first you define and initialize a a variable `Ptr`, then the compiler thinks you are doing that a second time.

The first error "error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'" pops up because the compiler thinks this is old legacy "C90" code. Back in the days it was valid to declare a variable without specifying the type, in which case it would implicitly default to `int`. This behavior was removed as per the C99 version of C in 1999.

The second error is a follow up to the first - since the compiler thinks you meant to write `int Ptr = "NULL";`, it detects a conflict with a previous variable `char* Ptr`, hence "error: redefinition of 'Ptr' with a different type: 'int' vs 'char *'"

Here we might note the difference between variable declaration and definition. We may actually declare a variable at file scope multiple times, as long as each declaration have the same type - this is meant to be used for sharing variables with external linkage across multiple files. But there can only be one definition of that variable in the project, and as soon as you add an initializer, you have a definition.

(There should also be a 3rd compiler error here: attempting to assign a character array to an integer - `int Ptr = "NULL";` is invalid C regardless if `Ptr` was declared/defined before or not.)